# Removing a metal rainwater storage tank

Tags: pipe, removal, asbestos

I want to remove my metal rainwater storage tanks, because it quite old and leaking.

This is a temporary fix as the house will later be redeveloped -- I just want to remove the water tank now.

It is filled from rainwater that comes from the roof, down a metal pipe and then down an asbestos pipe. My plan it is remove the asbestos pipe and then connect the metal pipe from the roof with the metal pipe below it -- the bit marked in green in the photo.

I have special bags to store the asbestos in after I have removed it (sent by the local council).

I'm not sure how to remove the asbestos pipe -- i.e. what tools to use. I think I would cut the metal pipe above the join. I'm worried that when I cut it, that the metal pipe (which might be supported by the asbestos pipe) falls down.

When I have removed the asbestos pipe, what is the best tool to chop up the water tank so I can remove it?

Any help would be appreciated. This just has to work -- not look pretty (as it is going to be replaced).

[image: everything]

[image: join]

[image: water tank]

Comment: I don't think this is a DIY job, hire a contractor who knows how.

Comment: Are you sure it's asbestos?  It looks like just an insulating wrapping on probably a steel pipe, I'd guess insulating to prevent freeze in the pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the upper metal pipe is supported at its lower end by a ring and a pair of rods stuck into the wall.  I hope it's a pair, I can only see the one on the right side.    You should inspect those, see if they are intact, see if they are in fact holding up the metal pipe.  Something must be and it's probably not the horizontal pipe.

It looks like the tank should be easy to cut up with power shears.  It's hard to tell from the picture but the metal looks within the capacity of a reasonably priced pair of shears.  Read and watch tutorials on how to not cut your hands and arms up while using them!

That's two parts of your question.  Can't help with cutting asbestos.   Best practice probably involves expensive encapsulation .... you are unlikely to get written advice that says to do anything less, such as wearing an N100 respirator, hosing it down and using a saw.

You should rent very sturdy work platforms to do this work and really you should hire a pro to do it because standing up on a ladder with a heavy tool in one hand and severing a very heavy object from the wall  has some dangers that I hope are obvious and it's not the kind of thing that you are likely to either have, or need, experience with for DIY work.  The issue is not "cutting a pipe" it's cutting and freeing a large, heavy, unwieldy object while standing on a ladder.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

That looks like cast iron pipe. If so, you can use a chain cutting tool or a diamond impregnated sawzall blade. A diamond cut off wheel for an angle grinder would also work. Don't worry too much about the asbestos. Just wear an N95 mask and you're also outside, so you should be fine.

Comment: Might be right about the work being outside, but usually when asbestos is mentioned, there is a mountain of paper work to do plus inspectors.